# How to sign in with Apple and Google credentials in react-native and supabase

Tags: firebase, react-native, authentication, session, supabase

I have been trying to implement sign in with google and apple using the following libraries and supabase in bare react-native projects.

- [react-native-apple-authentication](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-apple-authentication)
- [react-native-google-signin](https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin)

They work very well with firebase as described [here](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/social-auth) using firebase sdk.
The concept is fairly simple, the native sdk for both apple and google sign return user credential after a successful sign in . Here is an example from https://rnfirebase.io/auth/social-auth

#### With google credential

```js
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import { GoogleSignin } from '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin';

async function onGoogleButtonPress() {
  // Get the users ID token
  const { idToken } = await GoogleSignin.signIn();

  // Create a Google credential with the token
  const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);

  // Sign-in the user with the credential
  return auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
}
```

#### With apple credential

```js
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import { appleAuth } from '@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication';

async function onAppleButtonPress() {
  // Start the sign-in request
  const appleAuthRequestResponse = await appleAuth.performRequest({
    requestedOperation: appleAuth.Operation.LOGIN,
    requestedScopes: [appleAuth.Scope.EMAIL, appleAuth.Scope.FULL_NAME],
  });

  // Ensure Apple returned a user identityToken
  if (!appleAuthRequestResponse.identityToken) {
    throw 'Apple Sign-In failed - no identify token returned';
  }

  // Create a Firebase credential from the response
  const { identityToken, nonce } = appleAuthRequestResponse;
  const appleCredential = auth.AppleAuthProvider.credential(identityToken, nonce);

  // Sign the user in with the credential
  return auth().signInWithCredential(appleCredential);
}
```

I have gone through the auth provided by supabase here [supabase-js auth](https://supabase.io/docs/reference/javascript/auth-signin)
The closest thing I can find related to the implementation above is the use of a refresh-token as shown here
[Sign in using a refresh token](https://supabase.io/docs/reference/javascript/auth-signin#sign-in-using-a-refresh-token-eg-in-react-native)

```js
// An example using Expo's `AuthSession`
const redirectUri = AuthSession.makeRedirectUri({ useProxy: false });
const provider = 'google';

AuthSession.startAsync({
  authUrl: `https://MYSUPABASEAPP.supabase.co/auth/v1/authorize?provider=${provider}&redirect_to=${redirectUri}`,
  returnUrl: redirectUri,
}).then(async (response: any) => {
  if (!response) return;
  const { user, session, error } = await supabase.auth.signIn({
    refreshToken: response.params?.refresh_token,
  });
});
```

The example above uses a **refreshToken** parameter  *auth.sign()* to create a session for a user who is already registered.

**Correct me if am wrong.** According to the auth documentation there is no method that allows one to create a user using an auth credential. This is because of how gotrue social auth is implemented. The only solution I can think of as now is to move the entire auth logic to the backend and handle it on the web. This is not elegant at all since it will have to involve ugly deep-linking or webview implementations to  use supabase session and access token.

Given the scenario above, is there way of using native social sdk  in react-native to create a new user account in supabase using a user credential without having to force them use an email link,  password or web ?   Any ideas , answers or corrections are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, Signing in with third party credentials is not implemented in gotrue(Module used for auth in supabase) yet. If you have a native app, flutter app and react-native app that needs social auth using credentials follow up on this [WIP:PR](https://github.com/supabase/gotrue/pull/189). For further information refer to [Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE)](https://auth0.com/docs/authorization/flows/authorization-code-flow-with-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce).